# How to access point arraylist from another class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

When the activity is running, circles are drawn from an arraylist. When the user fling to the right , the point from the arraylist are saved into another arraylist(pointa). In another class, the arraylist(pointa) are supposed to be drawn as circles. However, it seems that it cannot get the x and y points of the arraylist(pointa). Can u help me identify where is the problem? Thank you.

```
    public class EyeTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int z = 0;
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
    TestView testview;
    public ArrayList<Point> pointa;

    public ArrayList<Point> pointlist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        testview = new TestView(this);
        setContentView(testview);

        // get the gesture detector
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(EyeTestActivity.this, new   SwipeGestureDetector(testview));

    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }


    public class TestView extends View {



        Paint paint;


        public TestView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init();

            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            createPointList();


        }



        public void init() {
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        }


        public void createPointList() {

            pointlist = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                float a = 100 * i;
                float b = 100 * i;
                for (int j = 1; j <= 24; j++) {
                    float x = (float) (a * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(15 * j)));
                    float y = (float) (b * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(15 * j)));

                    pointlist.add(new Point(x, y));
                    Log.i("new point " , x+", " +y);

                    //Add the x and y coordinates to the Point

                }
            }
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            Point point2 = pointlist.get(z);

            canvas.drawCircle(point2.getX() + canvas.getWidth() / 2, point2.getY() + canvas.getHeight() / 2, 15, paint);
            Log.i("onDraw " , " canvas drawing for z " + z + " at position " + point2.getX() + canvas.getWidth() / 2 + ", " + point2.getY() + canvas.getHeight() / 2);
        }
    }

    public class SwipeGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
        ArrayList<Point> pointa = new ArrayList<Point>();
        Intent intent = new Intent(EyeTestActivity.this, ResultExplanationActivity.class);


        TestView testview;

        public SwipeGestureDetector(TestView testview) {
            this.testview = testview;
        }

        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

        }

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            testview.invalidate();
            Log.i("onFling", " testview invalidate");
            if (e1.getX() < e2.getX()) {
                z++;



                if (z >=120) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                testview.invalidate();


                Point point2 = pointlist.get(z);
                pointa.add(new Point(point2.getX(), point2.getY()));

                return true;
            }

            if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) {

                z++;
                if (z >=120) {
                    finish();

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                testview.invalidate();



                return true;

            }

            if (e1.getY() < e2.getY()) {


            }

            if (e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {


            }

            return false;
        }
    }
        public ArrayList<Point> getPointa() {
            return this.pointa;
        }


}



    //another class( draw circles from pointa)

    public class ResultExplanationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EyeTestActivity eyetest;
    ResultView resultView;

    public ResultExplanationActivity() {
        eyetest = new EyeTestActivity();
        ArrayList<Point> pointa = eyetest.getPointa();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        resultView = new ResultExplanationActivity.ResultView(this);
        setContentView(resultView);
        ArrayList<Point> pointa = eyetest.getPointa();
        // get the gesture detector

    }


    public class ResultView extends View {

        ArrayList<Point> pointa = eyetest.getPointa();
        Paint paint;
        Paint painta;


        public ResultView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init();

            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


        }


        public void init() {
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            painta = new Paint();
            painta.setColor(Color.RED);
            painta.setStrokeWidth(5);
            painta.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        }



        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            for (int i=0;i<pointa.size();i++){
                canvas.drawCircle(pointa.getX() + canvas.getWidth() / 2, pointa.getY() + canvas.getHeight() / 2, 10, paint);
            }

        }
    }
}
```